# How do CSS radio tabs work?

Tags: html, css, tabs, radio-button

Could someone explain how the last part of the code works? Specifically:

```
[type=radio]:checked  {
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm just starting with CSS as a newb and wanted to try to create some interactive CSS tabs; which lead me to look at some existing code out there. Needless to say it has left me quite confused.

Why is `[type=radio]:checked` needed? It had `z-index: 2;` inside the brackets but I took that out and the code still works just fine; although when I try and delete `[type=radio]:checked` all together the code breaks. Why? It has no properties currently.

`[type=radio]:checked ~ .content` used to be `[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content` but I took out label and it still works fine. Why was it ever needed?

HTML:

```
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           tab#1
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">
           tab#2
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           tab#3
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;

}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

[type=radio]:checked  {
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your CSS:

```
[type=radio]:checked  {
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This is giving a `z-index` to the class content. Since only one tab is clicked it is giving a `z-index` to only one content class and that makes it display. (Since no others have a `z-index`)

If you want to see how it works then add a `z-index` to the content class, lets say 10, in your CSS and watch how it gets all screwy. Now since that code is only giving a `z-index: 1;` it doesn't display correctly since they all have 10 in this example. Now go to the above snidbit of code and put a `z-index: 11`; and watch how it works correctly. Since only one gets a high `z-index: 11;` it becomes the displaying one.

If you don't know what the `[type=radio]:checked` means, it is pertaining to an active state or clicked state for that radio input.

This part of code: `[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content` is allowing a more distinguished and precise selection of a DOM element. It will work without it because `.content` is below the `radio` tag. It will only apply to an element that is 1. `input radio` > 2. `label` > 3. `.content`.

If you also don't know what `z-index` does then let me know and I'll brake that down.

Comment: I understand how z-index works, what I don't understand is how the selectors [type=radio]:checked and checked ~ .content are working. What is [type-radio]: checked { } actually doing? I know that :checked refers to whichever radio is checked but I'm not understanding the concept of how they're being used with one another and in relation to the rest of the code, other than :checked ~. content displays the content of the checked box. The confusing thing is what :checked{} is doing and why it's needed.

Comment: Okay since you are clicking one of the three tabs on the top. Each one of those are an `input type=radio`, this is like an old fashion radio. You used to push one button in on the radio and the button that was current pushed in would pop out. Just like how radio buttons work on the web. That line of CSS is stating that the radio button that is clicked add a `z-index` to content. Since only one radio button can be active at a time it is the only one that has a higher `z-index` and therefor makes it display over the others.

Comment: I figured it out, my question is actually faulty because  [type=radio]:checked isn't needed, I previous said it was. I made a mistake when testing, and believed that snip of code was needed for it to work. But it's actually not needed at all which was what had confused me. Thanks for the answer though, my mistake!

Comment: Oh no problem! I am glad I could have helped. Best of luck mate.