# Animated submenu pure css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I tried to make a menu, which has 3 menu items and 1 subitem. If I click on second item, first child item should display. But not normally display it. It should animate it and slide it. I think there is a way with `transition` but I don't really know CSS3. And I want to have a pure css solution.

Here my HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Second</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">First child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I created this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kEg4/)**. Now I want to show `First child` menu item slowly if I click on `Second` menu item.

The only thing that I did before was checking `transition` but I just don't get it.

Can someone give me a hint?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/3kEg4/3/

```
#menu {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0CF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0C3;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
}
```

(inspired from http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/2BqGY/)

Comment: Mh, I've tested it on my computer now (yesterday I've tested it with my handy) and it works on hover. You know a jQuery script that this effect appears by menu item click?

Comment: Tou can use the checkbox hack if you want the effect to appear on click event see sample here : http://dabblet.com/gist/1507175

Answer (score 1):

You can use some CSS3 animations to achieve this effect.

```
#menu ul li ul{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: .6s ease;
  -o-transition: .6s ease;
  height: 0;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/3kEg4/4/)

**radio active states**

[JSFIDDLE Radio](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UbF9a/)

[Stackoverflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237560/how-do-css-radio-tabs-work/19237661#19237661)

**jQuery**

```
$('.subMenu').on('click', function() {
  $('.subMenu ul').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/5NGqW/)

Comment: LEt me add some styles to this `ul` and it'll look real nice :p

Comment: Is it possible to get this effect with `click` instead of `hover`?

Comment: @rschweri Not in pure CSS unless you use the checkbox hack.. You would otherwise need JS if you want `click` events. 1+ Nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah but with the use of jQuery if you want a click action or I believe you can use an radio button to active a clicked state.

Comment: Mh what a pity :/ So I have to do it in jQuery? Could you provide a code snippet? :)

Comment: I'll provide you with the jquery and I have a SO question pertaining to radio active states with a fiddle.

Comment: Okay, but you have to know, I'm totally new to jQuery and I didn't use it before. Coule you help me? That would be great :)

Comment: Please see my updated answer with a radio button pure css solution and my jquery solution. jQuery is very easy to get the hang of and it only requires this tiny little function to do it!

Comment: Also if you need help linking up the jQuery library then just ask!

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better

```
#menu ul li ul{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
} 

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Works great as well. Please do add prefixes. Hope this helps someone.